# python remove outliers, filter and do the mean

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, mean, outliers

I try to remove outliers of dataset with filter on colone and do the mean.
I succes it separately but I fail with both.

```
df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2',  column_3', 'column_4']).quantile([0.05, 0.95])


df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2',  column_3', 'column_4']).mean()
```

This code give me 2 datasets but i looking for remove outliers before I do the mean. Is it possible with groupby or I need do it manually ?
If it's possible do you know, what method can I use ?

Thank's and sorry if my english is bad

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your code example is missing a ' in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of the first command back to a new dataframe, which you can then take the mean of:

```
df_temp = df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2',  'column_3', 'column_4']).quantile([0.05, 0.95])


df_temp.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2',  'column_3', 'column_4']).mean()
```

Comment: But if I'm right,  this solution dont remove outliers of dataset before the mean

Comment: This code do a mean with just 2 values 0.05 and 0.95.

Comment: This is because you are using quantile wrong... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html